# Delete all in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

i have an association for a user as `user  has_many agents` and `agent belongs_to user`.
**in rails console**,i am trying to use different users to test a particular scenario and i want a user with no agents,hence i want to delete the `user.agents`.
i tried `user.agents.map(&:destroy)`,but it gives error as `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError: Attempted to delete a stale object`.i even tried `user.agents.delete_all` but it too does not work.can i delete the users agents with a single command in **rails console**.

Answer (score 23):

You better use `destroy` because it goes through all the Rails magic (callbacks and such)

```
user.destroy #For a single record
user.agents.destroy_all #For a collection
```

Comment: i want to destroy `user.agents` and I tried `user.agents.destroy,but it gives me error.

Comment: it's either `user.destroy` either `user.agents.destroy_all`. First one act on a single record, second one act on a collection

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for a `.destroy_all` method. It destroys all records of a given collection.
So `user.agents.destroy_all`, would return an empty array for `user.agents`.

You could not have used `.delete_all` because it is a class method and it deletes records that match a given condition. Like this, `Agent.delete_all(condition)`. If used without a condition it deletes all records from a matched table.

Keep in mind that `.destroy` methods are instance methods. They instantiate an object and perform callbacks before erasing it. `.delete` methods are class methods and they directly erase an object.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
user.agents.find_each(&:destroy)
```

Comment: I like the sound of "find each and destroy". XD

Answer (score -1):

```
ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
```

Is for [Optimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html), remove any locks you have on it before trying to delete again. Check if anyone else is using the system or submit any forms you have open.